# Filter GridView with Multiple 'DropDownList with Multi-Select' using jQuery Select2

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to Filter GridView with Multiple 'DropDownList with Multi-Select' using **jQuery Select2**.

I'm following the codes from this link >> https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/182622/Filter-GridView-with-multi-select-DropDownList-using-jQuery-Select2-Plugin-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet/ this can only filter gridview using one dropdown. My requirement is to filter gridview using two dropdowns with Multi-Select.

***I'm getting stuck at 'condition1' and 'where' condition in the below code***

Any help or lead to fix the below code is highly appreciated.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ddlCountries.DataBind()
    End If


End Sub

Protected Sub OnSearch(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim query As String = " SELECT distinct([CUSTOMER_NAME_CMT]),[Acc Number] FROM dbo.MASTERDATA_PRO"


    Dim condition As String = String.Empty
    For Each item As String In hfSelected.Value.Split(","c)
        condition += String.Format("'{0}',", item)
    Next


    Dim condition1 As String = String.Empty
    For Each item As String In hfSelected_ACCNO.Value.Split(","c)
        condition1 += String.Format("'{0}',", item)
    Next


    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) Then
        condition = String.Format(" WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME_CMT IN ({0})  ", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1))

    End If


    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(condition1) Then
        condition1 = String.Format(" and [Acc Number] IN ({0}) ", condition1.Substring(0, condition1.Length - 1))

    End If


    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(query & condition & condition1 ) 
   GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Function GetData(ByVal query As String) As DataTable
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conString)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query)
            Using sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                cmd.Connection = con
                Using dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    Return dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, unfortantly that example is a mess - and does not work correctly.

And it has extras things like that hidden field in the markup that's not even used.

However, there are "several issues that crop up"

First up?

Unfortantly the asp.net "dropdown" list control does not work if you want multi-select to work.

However, have no fear - just use the standard "HTML" "select" tag.
And MORE interesting, is that the select tag quite much supports darn near everything the DropDownList supports (they are actually much the same - the asp.net is based on it. In fact ALL of the settings are much the same, and you can even use data bound.

(for most dropdowns - yes, I recommend you continue to use dropDownList).

however, that "select2" jQuery add-in? It has issues.

So, here is working example. (we will select some Cities, and display hotels).

So, our markup looks like this:

```
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select City(s) for Hotels" Style="float:left;margin-right:25px" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>

            <select ID="cboCity" runat="server" Style="width:200px"
                DataTextField="City" 
                DataValueField="City"
                CssClass="form-control"
                ClientIDMode="Static">
            </select>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" style="margin-left:25px"/>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div style="clear:both;float:left;width:60%">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table table-hover" ></asp:GridView>
        </div>
</form>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cboCity").select2({
            placeholder: 'Select city(s)',
            allowClear: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

our code behind can look like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' load our combo
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT City from City ORDER BY City",
               New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            cboCity.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            cboCity.DataBind()
            cboCity.Multiple = True
        End Using

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM VHotels ",
               New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

        Dim strWhere = ""
        For Each MySelect As ListItem In cboCity.Items
            If MySelect.Selected Then
                With cmdSQL.Parameters
                    If strWhere <> "" Then strWhere &= ","
                    strWhere &= "@" & .Count
                    .Add("@" & .Count, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = MySelect.Value
                End With
            End If
        Next

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        cmdSQL.CommandText &= "WHERE City in (" & strWhere & ") ORDER BY HotelName"
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

The results look like this:

[image]

Note carefull how we had to remove the select=multiple from the markup - it does not work if you do that - but in the page load when we load up the combo box, note the code setting cboCity.Multiple = True.